# Where should I put my web app so it is private by default but accessible through subdomains?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, subdomain

I have a web application written in PHP that I want to host on an Apache 2.2 server. The tricky part though is that the same web application should be accessible through different subdomains (the web application uses the current subdomain to do some work). In other words I don't want to have to deploy a different copy of the web app for every subdomain. This also means that the "main" copy of the web app should be out of reach, the web app should only be accessible through subdomains.

That's pretty much it, thanks for any ideas.

PS: If you think that this is a bad idea for any reason I'm also interested as I'm still considering all my options.

Comment: What you would like to achieve is called "multi-tenancy". Usually, your application needs to be aware of how to do this.

Comment: My application is aware in the sense that it already distinguishes between different subdomains internally and serves the correct data. My issue currently is how to deploy it on the server. Locally I just have the application in a specific directory of my webserver and I use virtual hosts to point a specific subdomain to the directory where my web app resides.

Comment: That sounds like exactly the sort of configuration you would set up on the live server, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install your application outside the DocumentRoot and use the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive to make it available within the specific VirtualHost entries you set up for subdomains.

```
Alias /app /var/www/apps/appname
```

You application can then use the [SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name) to determine which virtual host is being accessed if you need to do anything specific per subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have your site setup as the default vhost.

On RHEL/CentOS leave the default site setup as /var/www/html and set your main site up as /var/www/example.com/html.  Any request not to example.com or an alias will go to the default site.